# Link: fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined VS2015 developer cmd window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, console-application

I have read a ton of this same question, but I appear to be doing everything correctly as all suggestions advise, but am still getting this error.

I have simple .cpp and .h files in C++ using Visual Studio 2015. My program runs perfect from the gui. I need to run it in the visual studio developer command window to get the results there, this is a verified console application. I have copied the files to their own directory using:

```
C:\RunDirectory>copy C:\SaveDirectory\
```

The system verifies that it copies all 15 files.

When I run this command:

```
C:\RunDirectory>cl Aprogram.cpp
```

Then I get the error.

I have a main that is returning an int, and this is a console application with the correct linker settings: `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`

Any ideas? I'm pretty stumped.

This is my driver file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "JollyBanker.h"

  using namespace std;

int main()
{
        JollyBanker theBanker;
        theBanker.BuildQueue("BankTransIn.txt");
        theBanker.ProcessQueue();
        theBanker.DisplayResults();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can build your app in Visual Studio and then run it from a console. It doesn't have to be built from a console.

Comment: I did build with VS, and when I try to run from the console I get the error

Comment: `cl Aprogram.cpp` is not how you run your app, it's how you (try to) build your app.

Comment: sorry, I may have used the wrong terminology. I run cl Aprogram.cpp and get the error, I also try cl aprogram>out.txt and get a file with the same error

Comment: My goal is to make sure it will work in a console outside of visual studio

Comment: After you build your app in Visual Studio - look for Aprogram.exe.  The .cpp file is source code, not an executable.  You should be able to double click the icon in explorer, or simply type Aprogram.exe into your console window when you are in the appropriate directory.  Listen to @JonathanPotter - he's got it right.

Answer (score 2):

File `Aprogram.cpp` is a source code file, which is compiled and linked
into an executable by Visual Studio IDE. Assuming that default project
settings are used, this executable is located in "Debug" or "Release" 
subdirectory of the directory that contains your solution and it is named
`ProjectName.exe` (where "ProjectName" is the name of the project
within the solution that contains `Aprogram.cpp`)

Also, you mentioned that you want to make sure it works outside VS. Note
that if you have used the default settings, you will have problems when you
run this executable on another machine. To solve this, I suggest that you
change the runtime library that you are linking to. To do this, right click on
the project in Solution Explorer and select "Properties". Go to "C/C++" -> "Code Generation"
and change the value of "Runtime Library" to "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)" for "Debug" configuration, or to "Multi-threaded (/MT)" for "Release" configuration.